# Persistencia de "fs.watch"

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Trabajo en *NodeJS*, un conocido me recomendó que hiciera un **watchdog (supervisión)** en la que cuando un comando es modificado, éste se recargaría automáticamente (tras haber sido guardado). En la documentación de *NodeJS* encontré lo siguiente:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Sin embargo, no sé qué procesos hace esto, es decir, su persistencia, si revisa si los archivos han sido modificados tras periodos de tiempo, o acciona sólo cuando el archivo ha sido modificado en lugar de hacer ciclos.

Ni tampoco sé si sería lo más eficiente, estoy abierto a sugerencias.

Actualmente, tengo el siguiente código para cargar todos los comandos que están dentro del directorio **/cmd/**.

```
fs.readdir(`./cmd/`, (err, files) => {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.log(logwhite(
        `Loading a total of ` + loggreen(files.length) + ` commands.`
    ));
    const launch = new Date().getTime();
    files.forEach(f=> {
        let props = require(`./cmd/${f}`);
        var date = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(
            `${loggreen(date - launch)}ms   ` +
            loggray(`Loading Command: ${props.help.name}        `) +
            loggreen(` Status OK`)
        );
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
        props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
        });
    });
});
```

Al igual, tengo lo siguiente para **recargar** un comando, el cual uso `reload {comando}`:

```
let command;
if (bot.commands.has(params[0])) {
  command = params[0];
} else if (bot.aliases.has(params[0])) {
  command = bot.aliases.get(params[0]);
}
if (!command) {
  return msg.channel.sendMessage(`I cannot find the command: ${params[0]}`);
} else {
  msg.channel.sendMessage(`Reloading: ${command}`)
    .then(m => {
      bot.reload(command)
        .then(() => {
           m.edit(`Successfully reloaded: ${command}`);
        })
        .catch(e => {
           m.edit(`Command reload failed: ${command}\n\`\`\`${e.stack}\`\`\``);
        });
    });
}
```

Un conocido me ha aconsejado que usara `fs.watch`, y mi pregunta era que si `fs.watch` revisaba los cambios periódicamente (los revisa en un intervalo de tiempo), o revisa los cambios cuando un archivo ha sido modificado (como un evento).

Lo que quiero hacer es que, cuando un archivo haya sido modificado, que se ejecute un comando parecido al que tengo de `reload {comando}`, es decir, modifico un archivo, lo guardo, y el programa lo recarga automáticamente, sin necesidad de usar el comando reload.

¿Es `fs.watch` lo más eficiente para esta tarea? Y si es así, ¿Cómo debería usarlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Mi pregunta es el nivel de persistencia de `fs.watch`, cómo funciona, es decir, cómo detecta los cambios de los archivos, yo quiero hacer que cuando modifique un archivo y lo guarde, mi programa lo 'recargue' y así puedo seguir trabajando con todos los cambios aplicados, en sustitución del comando 'reload' que tengo.

Comment: [Aquí](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) está la documentación, lo que te puedo decir es que esa función lo que hace es vigilar el archivo, o el directorio que quieras, cada vez que ocurre un cambio en un archivo, este recibe un evento de acuerdo a lo que haya sucedido (cambio en el archivo, cambio de nombre, archivo borrado, archivo creado, archivo movido) y te retorna en su evento el archivo en el cual ocurrió el cambio, para recargar creo que debes usar procesos, si te sirve esto, puedo ampliar la respuesta con la parte de procesos

Comment: Sí, la parte de procesos es algo que necesito fundamentalmente. Voy a añadir un pedazo de código que tengo para cargar los comandos.

Comment: Editado. ¿Hace falta añadir algo más?

Comment: Si es lo más eficiente, trataré de editar tu pregunta para que la reabran y poder hacer bien la respuesta, de lo contrario tendrás que hacer una pregunta nueva, tratar de que no sea cerrada por tema basado en opiniones y allí te podré responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar `fs.watch` basta con hacer esto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
// var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


(function start() {
    // aqui puedes cargar todos los comandos, tal cual lo haces al principio
})();

// pasas el archivo o directorio que quieras observar
const DIRECTORY = './cmd'
fs.watch(DIRECTORY, {encoding: 'buffer', recursive: true}, (eventType, fileName) => {
    // el primer parametro es el directorio que vigilirá
    // el segundo, es un objeto con el encoding, en este caso un buffer, y si va a ser recursivo(en sistemas basados en LINUX esta opcion no afecta, ver Nota)
    // el tercero, es el callback que recibe 2 argumentos

    if (eventType == 'change' && fileName) {
        // en este punto ya tienes el nombre del archivo, que puedes abrirlo con fs.readFile y hacer lo que quieras, o recargarlo como quieras.
        // en el caso que quieras recargar todos, puedes volver a llamar la funcion start();
    }
})
```

**Nota:** El parametro de recursivo en las opciones, solo funciona en windows, de modo que el observador o watch solo puede observar archivos y carpetas que estén en el nivel de la carpeta en la cual se ponga a escuchar, por lo que si tienes archivos dentro de carpetas hijas a este directorio, estas no tendrán el evento si es que posees un Linux.

No añadí la parte de los procesos, porque veo que estas recargando los comandos con alguna libreria (no se de donde sale ese bot), por lo que no sé muchas de las funciones que tienes

Comment: `fs.watch` recarga el archivo múltiples veces, 2-3 (he hecho un console.log dentro del if, y manda 2-3 mensages a la consola, todos son de eventType == 'change'). Y, no, no uso librerías externas para la carga/actualización de los comandos, es simplemente exports.